# Does $2\int_0^\infty P[X \ge t] t dt $ have meaning for 'general' random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Does 
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\infty P[X \ge t] t dt 
\end{align}
have any meaning for a general random variable?

It is well known that for positive random variables 
\begin{align}
2\int_0^\infty P[X \ge t] t dt= E[X^2]
\end{align}

If $X$ is a symmetric random variable then
\begin{align}
P[|X| \ge t]  =2 P[ X\ge t]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
2\int_0^\infty P[X \ge t] t dt= \int_0^\infty P[ |X| \ge t] t dt=  \frac{1}{2}E[X^2]
\end{align}

What about a more general set case of $X$?

Comment: Split $X$ into positive and negative parts. Then you will get similar relations for the expectation of $X$ restricted to be negative or positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}[\max(X,0)^2]$, if you consider that "meaningful".
More generally,
$$ \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq t)\;t^n\;\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{n+1}\mathbb{E}\left[\max(X,0)^{n+1}\right],$$
assuming $\mathbb{P}(X \geq t) \in o(1/t^{n+1})$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah. That can work. Can you show me how you got this?

Comment: Just do an integration by parts: $2 \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq t) t dt =  \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \geq t) dt^2  = \left.\mathbb{P}(X \geq t) t^2 \right|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty t^2 d \mathbb{P}(X \geq t)$, etc..